# How to insert all values into database using drupal 7

Tags: php, database, drupal-7, nodes, sql-insert

I am trying to insert values into database in Drupal 7 but It is inserting only first and one record. Here is my code:

```
    $node = node_load($node->nid);

    $result = db_select('network_drive_listing', 'n')
    ->fields('n', array('filename'))
    ->condition('n.is_dir',0)
    ->distinct()
    ->range(0, 10)
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();

    $node->field_select_images[$node->language][0]['nid'] = $result; // Here I am assigning values of database
```

Above in $result I am getting 10 values if I dump but It is inserting only 1 record into database. Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

"db_select" using "fetchAll()" gives you an array with 10 results.

I suggest you do a foreach $result as $r and do something like this:

```
$node->field_select_images[$node->language][$id++]['nid'] = $r;
```

You may also check this:
https://drupaldeveloper.in/codelet/drupal-create-drupal7-node-programmatically